# Auto cout each cin

Tags: c++, cin, cout, istream, filebuf

I am trying to print automatically each variable which gets input from cin.

```
class MyFileBuf : public std::filebuf
{
protected:
    virtual std::streamsize xsgetn (char* p, streamsize n)
    {
        std::streamsize ret = std::filebuf::xsgetn( p, n );
        cout << p;
        return ret;
    };
};


class MyFileStream : public std::istream
{
public:
    MyFileStream() : std::istream( 0 ) { init( &buf_ ); };
    MyFileStream( const char* filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::in )
    : std::istream( 0 )
    {
        init( &buf_ );
        this->open( filename, mode );
    }

    bool is_open() const { return buf_.is_open(); };

    void close() { buf_.close(); };

    void open( const char* filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::in )
    {
        buf_.open( filename, mode );
    };

    std::filebuf* rdbuf() { return &buf_; };

private:
    MyFileBuf buf_;
};
```

this is my streams classes. Than I tried to set the cin buffer to the MyFileStream buffer, but the problem that the function xsgetn is not even called once.
How can I fix it? if I try to do the same for output stream, with xsputn it works and the function is called.

I do it because I want that the output stream will contain also the input stream, and than I can get the whole console content. Maybe there's another solution for it?

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra work to replicate `std::cin >> some_variable; std::cout << some_ariable;`

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to inherit the standard I/O interfaces.

Comment: I do it because I want that the output stream will contain also the input stream, and than I can get the whole console content. Maybe there's another solution for it?